# Boost Python, Visual Studio links to wrong boost dll

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, boost

I used dependency walker and found out that VS did not link to `boost_python3_...` but to `boost_python_...`. I removed the non 3 version, but now the linker complains that it cannot find `boost_python-vc140-mt-1_60.lib`. What do I have to do do link with the Python 3 boost library? Or are the non 3 versions also used for python 3?

Comment: which compiler are you using ?
For vc define BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB which turns auto linkage off.
Then explicitly add the .lib as additional linker input (settings/linker/input).
I've had the same problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153858/linking-against-boost-python-3-6-cant-find-boost-python-instead-of-boost-pytho

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I changed to pybind11 and do not remember which compiler I used at that time. I would guess the one that ships with vs2015

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, these are options that worked well for me:

1. Go to boost/python/detail/config.hpp and change BOOST_LIB_NAMe to boost_python3 instead of boost_python.
2. Turn auto Linkage of by defining BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB and then explicitly set boost_python3...lib as linker dependency.