# Linking against Boost python 3.6. can't find boost_python instead of boost_python3

Tags: python, c++, boost, linker, visual-studio-2017

I have problems linking against boost python.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and compiled the boost 1_64 package with the following command line:

```
b2 -a toolset=msvc-14.1 --build_type=complete stage variant=debugthreading=multi link=shared runtime-link=shared define=_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=0 address-model=64
```

with this user-config.jam:

```
using python 
: 3.6                   # Version
: C:\\Python36\\python.exe      # Python Path
: C:\\Python36\\include         # include path
: C:\\Python36\\libs            # lib path(s)
: <define>BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1
;
```

But while building my c++ project with runtime libary: Multi-threaded DLL (/MD) I keep getting this error message:

```
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'boost_python-vc141-mt-gd-1_64.lib'
```

but the boost libs I compiled contain the following boost_python files:

```
boost_python3-vc141-mt-gd-1_64.dll
boost_python3-vc141-mt-gd-1_64.lib
```

Does someone have experience with boost for python 3? After hours of trying, I can't find a good solution.
Btw.: renaming the files to boost_python- (removing the 3) works fine.
But I don't think that this is the correct way

---

**VC Project settings:**

Add. include directories:

```
C:\Python36\include;D:\ws\boost_1_64_0\boost_1_64_0;
```

Add. libary directories:

```
D:\ws\boost_1_64_0\boost_1_64_0\stage\lib;C:\Python36\libs;
```

---

Closed: The autolink feature of boost did not work correctly with python 3. The boost_module_name macro was set to boost_python (missing the 3) and the generated libs contained the 3.

**-->** Turned auto link off and added the required libs manually.

---

**Solution**
a) Go to boost/python/detail/config.hpp and change BOOST_LIB_NAMe to boost_python3 instead of boost_python.

or

**Solution**
b) Turn auto Linkage of by defining BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB and then explicitly set boost_python3...lib as linker dependency.

Comment: What are the build commands for your C++ project? Are you use something like `distutils.extension`?

Comment: I'm not using any special extensions or settings. all i did was creating a c++ 32 console aplication project and changed the code generation to DLL.
And added the requiered include paths of course

Comment: Please provide enough information. How is your C++ code compiled and, in particular, linked? Give the full command. Failing that, we cannot really help you, I'm afraid.

Comment: Is there a way to get the command from visual studio ?

Comment: I suspect that VS attempts to build a python (version 2), not a python3 module.

Comment: @Walter But where could this information come from ? I've added some project settings to the question. This is all i changed: the runtime libary and the include paths as given.

Answer (score 1):

You provide

```
boost_python3-vc141-mt-gd-1_64.dll
boost_python3-vc141-mt-gd-1_64.lib
```

but the error reports missing

```
boost_python-vc141-mt-gd-1_64.lib
```

(spot the difference!)

So obviously, your IDE (VS) attempts to build a python, not a python3 extension. I don't know VS, but there must be away to change that somewhere somehow.

Comment: I'Ve noticed the difference, sorry if this was not clear. but i still could not fidn a way to configure this in vs

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for coming in late here, just went through the same nonsense myself. Turns out that boost doesn't handle two installs very well (or even a py3.x by itself)

You can definitely solve this by going into `<boost/python/detail/config.hpp>` and making a quick change. To allow for boost to work with both python 2.x (2.7, presumably) and 3.x, I'd suggest changing:

`#define BOOST_LIB_NAME boost_python`

to

```
#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >=3
  #define BOOST_LIB_NAME boost_python3
#else
  #define BOOST_LIB_NAME boost_python
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to heads up here as this happened to me. [Here is the link.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45113365/3166476) It may have been that you included the 2.7 python headers instead of the 3.6. And yea, nothing about it is obvious, it really put me to work.