# Configuring Visual Studio to work with Boost.Python and Python 3

Tags: c++, python-3.x, visual-studio-2013, boost-python

I had Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2013 (Version 12.0.31101.00 Update 4) and Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017) on my PC with Windows 10 Pro.

In order to try examples with Boost.Python I downloaded boost 1.64.0 and build libraries by `b2` with options `--with-python --toolset=msvc --build-type=complete`. As a result I have the following files:

- boost_python3-vc120-mt-1_64.dll
- boost_python3-vc120-mt-1_64.lib
- boost_python3-vc120-mt-gd-1_64.dll
- boost_python3-vc120-mt-gd-1_64.lib
- libboost_python3-vc120-mt-1_64.lib
- libboost_python3-vc120-mt-gd-1_64.lib
- libboost_python3-vc120-mt-s-1_64.lib
- libboost_python3-vc120-mt-sgd-1_64.lib
- libboost_python3-vc120-s-1_64.lib
- libboost_python3-vc120-sgd-1_64.lib

Then I created project (type: Win32 / DLL) in Visual Studio with the following code taken [here](https://github.com/TNG/boost-python-examples/blob/master/01-HelloWorld/hello.cpp):

```cpp
char const* greet()
{
    return "hello, world";
}

#include <boost/python.hpp>

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("greet", greet);
}
```

In project properties for C/C++ settings I added "Additional Include Directories" to locations of Boost and Python (ends with \Python36\include).

During the first attempt to build the project an error appears:

> Error 1   error LNK1104: cannot open file 'python36.lib'

So in project properties for Linker settings "Additional Library Directories" I added corresponding location (ends with \Python\Python36\libs). After that I could move on ... to the next error:

> Error 1   error LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_python-vc120-mt-gd-1_64.lib'

It is noteworthy that the difference in filenames I had and VS2013 looking for is just digit `3` after word `python`.

Similar questions at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153858/linking-against-boost-python-3-6-cant-find-boost-python-instead-of-boost-pytho) and in [google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/caffe-users/_Iydbi8T-GQ/rGVJ7KAOCAAJ) are discussed but without valuable tips. The only useful information is that library file names `*boost_python-*` corresponds to Python 2 and `*boost_python3-*` to Python 3.

I noticed that changing the build type (Solution Configuration) from Debug to Release leads to change the error message in part of library file name (there is no `-gd-` now):

> Error 1   error LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_python-vc120-mt-1_64.lib'

I suppose, VS2013 knows boost library file name convention, but probably does not know the difference about Python 2 and Python 3.

**So, I have 3 questions:**

1. Is it possible to influence the logic used by VS to look for Boost.Python library? (Of course lib-files renaming is also an option, but I do not like this for some reason)
2. Do the linker options allow specifying lib-file directly? (i.e. I can write whole path to the `boost_python3-vc120-mt-1_64.lib` including file name, not just folder name in section "Additional Library Directories")
3. What option in the project properties should make VS2013 to use different LIB or DLL files, e.g. `libboost_python3-vc120-mt-1_64.lib` or `boost_python3-vc120-mt-1_64.dll` instead of `boost_python-vc120-mt-1_64.lib`?

Comment: Do you have something from python2 in the c++ include path, causing it to find the wrong Python.h while building your application?

Comment: @KennyOstrom There is no Python 2 installed at my PC, so Python.h can be taken only from ...\Python\Python36\include\. Perhaps some #define should be added to my code

Comment: in boost/python/detail/config.hpp does it have "#define BOOST_LIB_NAME boost_python"?  Did you put the python3 setup in config_user.jam before you built boost?  It looks like it knew it was python3, but the auto_link.hpp info is wrong?

Comment: @KennyOstrom File user-config.jam is used with the content like `using python : 3.6 : ... : define>BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 ;`.  In the config.hpp define is really `#define BOOST_LIB_NAME boost_python` (Should the value for `BOOST_LIB_NAME` be changed here? or auto_link.hpp should be found / created in order to change lib name?)

Comment: I would recommend using the Nuget package, https://www.nuget.org/packages/boost-vc120/

Comment: I'm still using python2 due to legacy reasons. You could try that, but I don't know why it's building one library and setting auto_link to load the wrong name.  Incidentally, you can ignore the release/debug thing because -gd- is just how they say "this is the debug build" (auto_link got that right).

Comment: Have you actually added the path to Boost libs it your `Additional Library Directories`? As for boost_python libs naming, with Python 3 `b2` creates 2 identical libs `boost_python-*` and `boost_python3-*`, but Boost auto-linking (works on Windows by default) uses the 1st one.

Comment: @RomanMiroshnychenko After investigation the issue I found that `b2` creates both or one of `boost_python-*` and `boost_python3-*` vepending on available Python versions and configuration (e.g. in `user-config.jam` can be `using python : 3 ....` and `using python : 2 ....` with references to corresponding folders). Visual Studio uses `BOOST_LIB_NAME` define to build name of lib-file, so there are two ways - answers to my 1st question: 1) change `BOOST_LIB_NAME` in boost/python/detail/config.hpp ; or 2) add `auto_link.hpp` for `python` that is not available in boost forder.

Comment: @T33C I have tryed nuget package for boost, and even after update VS2013 (I had Update 4, and now it is 5 as mentioned at nuget.org pages) I cannot use boost::python library. The reason is linker error: `Error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) struct _object * __cdecl boost::python::detail::init_module(struct PyModuleDef &,void (__cdecl*)(void))" (__imp_?init_module@detail@python@boost@@YAPAU_object@@AAUPyModuleDef@@P6AXXZ@Z)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the community help I have found answers to couple of the questions.

> 1. Is it possible to influence the logic used by VS to look for Boost.Python library?

Name of library depends on value defined as macro `BOOST_LIB_NAME` in file `boost/python/detail/config.hpp`.
I have tried to change line (108 in boost 1.64.0)

```
#define BOOST_LIB_NAME boost_python
```

to

```
#define BOOST_LIB_NAME boost_python3
```

And desirable library file changed from `boost_python-vc120-mt-1_64.lib` to `boost_python3-vc120-mt-1_64.lib`.

It should be noted, that instead of changing values in `config.hpp` file `auto_link.hpp` can be created and used with redefinition of `BOOST_LIB_NAME`.

> 3. What option in the project properties should make VS2013 to use different LIB or DLL files, e.g. `libboost_python3-vc120-mt-1_64.lib` or `boost_python3-vc120-mt-1_64.dll` instead of `boost_python-vc120-mt-1_64.lib`?

That is also regulated by defines.

In particular, adding to the beginning of my code (before `#include <boost/python.hpp>`) the line

```
#define BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB
```

forces MSVS to search file `libboost_python3-vc120-mt-1_64.lib` (or `libboost_python-vc120-mt-1_64.lib`), i.e. static lib.
And vice versa line

```
#define BOOST_PYTHON_DYNAMIC_LIB
```

or

```
#define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK
```

can be used to import code from a dll.