# VS Community 2017 : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_python3-vc141-mt-x64-1_66.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker, boost-python

As the title says ...

while :

- Linker -> Input -> Additional dependencies : boost_python3-vc141-mt-x64-1_66.lib (is well spelled)
- Linker -> Platform -> Active (x64)
- Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories : C:\boost_1_66_0\stage\lib

Any idea why ?

Thanks a lot for your contributions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configuring Visual Studio to work with Boost.Python and Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44987299/configuring-visual-studio-to-work-with-boost-python-and-python-3)

Comment: C:\boost_1_66_0\stage\lib  contains 'boost_python3-vc141-mt-x64-1_66.lib' ? Sure you modified AdditionalLibraryDirectories in all relevant configurations? (Release/Debug | x64)

Comment: Yes, for 'All Configurations' and at the head of pathlist.

I tried at its tail too.

Another thing : This strange message at the beginning of build.

1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: UFPython, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>uf_pyt.cpp
1>Info: Boost.Config is older than your compiler version - probably nothing bad will happen - but you may wish to look for an update Boost version.  Define BOOST_CONFIG_SUPPRESS_OUTDATED_MESSAGE to suppress this message.
1>