# Building boost python for msvc with python3 - Linker Error

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, boost

I am porting a Python Libary from python 2.7 to 3.6 on fresh installed Win10 with VS2013 and Anaconda Python 3.6 64bit.

The libariy contains a dll which is using boost python as a wrapper for python, so I have to recompile it.
As the previous boost libs were compiled against python 2.7 I again started from a fresh boost_1_63_0 and compiled it with the following settings in the `project-config.jam`

```
import option ;    

using msvc = 12.0;  
using python : 3.6 : C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3 ;   

option.set keep-going : false ;
```

using the these parameters

```
bjam.exe --with-python address-model=64 variant=release link=shared
--build-type=complete
```

I get a full set of compiled libs:

```
└───lib
    boost_numpy36-vc120-mt-x64-1_67.dll
    boost_numpy36-vc120-mt-x64-1_67.lib
    boost_python36-vc120-mt-x64-1_67.dll
    boost_python36-vc120-mt-x64-1_67.lib
    ...
    libboost_python36-vc120-mt-gd-x32-1_67.lib
    libboost_python36-vc120-mt-gd-x64-1_67.lib
    libboost_python36-vc120-mt-x32-1_67.lib
    libboost_python36-vc120-mt-x64-1_67.lib
    ...
    libboost_numpy36-vc120-mt-gd-x32-1_67.lib
    libboost_numpy36-vc120-mt-gd-x64-1_67.lib
    libboost_numpy36-vc120-mt-x32-1_67.lib
    libboost_numpy36-vc120-mt-x64-1_67.lib
```

As I had some issues with the linker I started a new Soulution in Visual Studio. The needed boost and Pyton folders have been added to the project C/C++-->general-->additional Include directories and also boost's `stage\libs` folder and python's `libs` folder were added to the additional libary directories for the linker.

I try to compile the minimal example below which works perfectly on my other system which is still running on the old python 2.7 based boost build:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#define BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB  
#define BOOST_LIB_NAME "boost_numpy"
#include <boost/config/auto_link.hpp>
#include <boost/python/numpy.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/numpy.hpp>
#include <boost/python/suite/indexing/vector_indexing_suite.hpp>
```

While compiling I get the following linker error

```
LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_numpy-vc120-mt-x64-1_67.lib'
```

So for some reason the build creates a lib named `boost_numpy36-vc120-mt-x64-1_67.lib` but the linker is still searching for a version without the python version `36`.

When I simply remove the python version from the lib I get the following linker error:

```
LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_pythonPY_MAJOR_VERSIONPY_MINOR_VERSION-vc120-mt-gd-x32-1_67.lib'
```

Any ideas what is happening here?

**[update]**

Ok, so after finding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44987299/configuring-visual-studio-to-work-with-boost-python-and-python-3?rq=1) question I realized that the  name is linked to the definition of the `BOOST_LIB_NAME` so I changed it to

```
#define BOOST_LIB_NAME "boost_numpy36"
```

But unfortunatell I still get the second link error:

```
LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_pythonPY_MAJOR_VERSIONPY_MINOR_VERSION-vc120-mt-gd-x32-1_67.lib'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able so solve the descibed error, but I found a set of precompiled libaries here:
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you mention about:

> LNK1104: cannot open file
>   'libboost_pythonPY_MAJOR_VERSIONPY_MINOR_VERSION-vc120-mt-gd-x32-1_67.lib'

was solved on [this](https://github.com/boostorg/python/commit/24313709a78c694af4ae29116cd06ea86585aa95) commit.

to get full context of the problem you can check [this](https://github.com/boostorg/python/issues/193)

Comment: Great @user1618465, I will try it out and update my question. I did not figure out in which version this change was implemented. Is it already present in the current release (1.67.0)?

Comment: No, it will be in the 1.68. So what I did is just applying the fix on the 1.67 manually since it's just a couple of files.
Cheers